# Outlook 365 Mail Rest API: Receiveing internal server error when retrieving an .eml attachment

Tags: api, rest, email, office365, office365api

I am trying to retrieve an attachment via the Outlook / Office 365 Mail API.  I sent an email from Google, to my Office 365 account with an .eml as an attachment.  when I retrieve the email I am getting an internal server error as a response.  I have tried with 2.0 and beta versions of the API. Is it possible to retrieve .eml attachments?

Request: 
`https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{message_id}/attachments`

Response:

```
{
"error": {
"code": "ErrorInternalServerError"
"message": "Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.ItemAttachmentType'
to type'Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.FileAttachmentType'."
}-
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the error, let me take a look and get back to you as to why you are receiving this error.

Comment: Thanks @VenkatAyyadevara-MSFT Looking forward to hearing your response!

Comment: Just posted an answer.  We  have identified a bug in the service and checked in a fix.  Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M.Fur - Sorry, it took a while to investigate but a fix has been checked in, and should be deployed worldwide by end of May.